# Restrict SelectInput Based on User

Tags: r, shiny, user-input, shiny-reactivity, selectinput

I am currently  trying to construct an app to visualize worker performance over time. I am trying to create a password protected dashboard where users marked as managers can view all other user stats, and non-manager users can only view their own stats. However I cannot get it to work. Here is what I have so far. The users list is employees matched with their username (2 variables) , and the credentials list is usernames and passwords (2 variables). The issue is somewhere with the observe function imo. If the user is not manager I want their selectinput button locked on their own name. ie. session$user==users$user

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
data<-read.csv("Data/data.csv")
data$Create.Date<-as.Date(data$Create.Date)
credentials<-unique(read.csv("Data/credentials.csv"))

ui<-secure_app(head_auth=tags$script(inactivity),
             dashboardPage(

dashboardHeader(title = "Services Dashboard"),

dashboardSidebar(
  selectInput("name","Select a User", users[,1]),
  dateRangeInput("date", "Select a Date Range",format="mm-dd-yy"),
  actionButton("go", "Go")
),

dashboardBody(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("table"),
)
)
)

server<-function(input, output, session){

res_auth<-secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials))

user<-reactive({
  session$user
}
)

manager<-reactive({
  if(user()=="manager"){
    return(TRUE)
  }else{
    return(FALSE)
  }
})

observe({
  if(manager()==FALSE){
    updateSelectInput(session, "names", "Select A User", 
choices=users$user[users$username==user()])
  }
 })

    
 masterdata<-eventReactive(input$go, {
  data %>%
    filter(
      as.Date(Create.Date) >= as.Date(input$date[1]),
      as.Date(Create.Date) <= as.Date(input$date[2]),
      Staff.Created == input$name)
  })

 aggdata<-eventReactive(input$go, {
  data %>%
    filter(
      as.Date(Create.Date) >= as.Date(input$date[1]),
      as.Date(Create.Date) <= as.Date(input$date[2]),
      Staff.Created == input$name)%>%
    summarise(`Services Provided in Period Selected`=sum(count))
    
 })

 output$plot<-renderPlotly({
  ggplot(masterdata(), 
         aes(x=Create.Date, y=count, label=count),
         xmin=input$date[1], xmax=input$date[2], ymin=0, fill = input$date)+
    xlab("Date")+
    ylab("Services Provided")+
    geom_line(group=1, colour="#000099")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.5, size=8))+
    scale_x_date(breaks = "days", date_labels = "%m.%d")+
    geom_point()
    })

  output$table<-renderTable({
  aggdata()
 })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and here is my error code: Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero

Comment: Use `req()` for all the user input variables `input$abc` and reactive functions `user()`, `manager()`, etc., on the server side in all the observers.

Comment: Are you aware that the ids don't match? The id of the `selectInput` in the ui function is "name". The `updateSelectInput` in the server references "names", however.

Answer (score 0):

I removed everything but a few essentials to mock what you want. What I changed is this:

I used the id of the select input consistently (in this sample it is "names"). Otherwise you are trying to access an `input` element that does not exist. This would simply return `null` when you are trying the read it.

Another possible cause could happen during initialisation. I am not exactly sure about the order in which things happen. But if `session$user` is not set when the code gets evaluated the first time, your code will assume a non-manager scenario and it will not be updated again once all the information is available. Hence:

- Check for `null`, too, when the reactive expression checks for manager rights. This might happen during initialisation.
- I added an `else` branch to restore all the names in the select input when a manager is logged in.

```
library(shiny)

users <- data.frame(
  username = LETTERS[1:10],
  user = letters[1:10]
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Needed for mocking the user id
  checkboxInput("MockScenario", "Mock a manager scenario"),

  # Original code
  selectInput("names", "Select a User", users$username),
  dateRangeInput("date", "Select a Date Range", format="mm-dd-yy"),
  actionButton("go", "Go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  user <- reactive({
    # session$user # is not used in this sample but the mock
    ## Mocked user
    if (input$MockScenario == TRUE)
      "manager"
    else
      sample(users$user, 1)
  })
  
  manager <- reactive({
    if (isTruthy(user()) && user() == "manager") {
      return(TRUE)
    } else {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if(manager() == FALSE) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "names", "Select A User", 
                        choices = users$username[users$user == user()])
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "names", "Select A User", 
                        choices = users$username)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```